# Is it possible to use "go mod tidy" to clear unused dependencies except indirect ones?

Tags: go, go-modules, go-swagger

I understand that it is the expected behavior of `go mod tidy` to prune dependencies tree by removing the unnecessary ones, but part of my CI uses `go-swagger` to generate swagger `JSON` files. So, in the end. `go mod tidy` will remove the `go-swagger` packages from `go.mod` file because they're listed as `//indirect` (they're not used directly from the source code). Is there a workaround?

Here's my `go.mod` file:

```golang
...
require (
    github.com/go-openapi/errors v0.20.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-openapi/validate v0.20.2 // indirect
    github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger v0.26.1 // indirect
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
    github.com/mailru/easyjson v0.7.7 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/afero v1.5.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/mod v0.4.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20210220033124-5f55cee0dc0d // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210220050731-9a76102bfb43 // indirect
    golang.org/x/tools v0.1.0 // indirect
)
```

After I run `go mod tidy`, only this one remains:

```golang
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
```

However, I have the following target on my Makefile that runs on production:

```sh
$ swagger generate spec -o ./internal/ui/swagger.json
```

I kind of wanted to avoid calling explictly `go get` on `go-swagger` globally after running `go tidy`.  Do you guys have any suggestion on how to workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `go install` to install swagger without affecting go.mod.**

In your `Makefile` have a separate target that installs the swagger deps then runs it.   Ours is arranged along these lines:

```
ROOT := $(PWD)
DIST := ${ROOT}/dist

# Could be /go or ${HOME}/go depending on build environment
export GOPATH := ${ROOT}/go

.PHONY: swagger

all: $(DIST)/app swagger

swagger: $(GOPATH)
    go install -v github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/cmd/swagger@latest
    $(GOPATH)/bin/swagger version
    $(GOPATH)/bin/swagger generate spec -o ./swagger-ui/swagger.json -m

$(DIST)/app: $(DIST) $(GOPATH)
    go build -v -o $(DIST)/app ./cmd/...

$(DIST):
    mkdir -p $(DIST)

$(GOPATH):
    mkdir -p $(GOPATH)
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect one workaround would be to:

- import explicitly in one of your project source .go file the package `github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/scan`
- define a dummy variable

  ```golang
  var _ = scan.Parse
  ```

That way, your sources would *directly* "use" `github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger`, which would no longer pruned by go mod tidy.

I would do that in a go file named `externalTools.go`, just to remember *why* this fake import is needed.

Comment: Would this not then bloat the final executable by linking all the swagger libs as well?

Comment: @EdRandall I suppose though. https://github.com/samlitowitz/goimportcycle, https://github.com/becheran/depgraph and https://github.com/nikolaydubina/go-binsize-treemap would be able to visualize any bloat. https://github.com/cugu/gocap would qualify their security issue. (That or nancy: https://jcdan3.medium.com/scanning-go-dependencies-for-vulnerabilities-b82db3d56b27)

Answer (score 0):

What about using this commands?

```
go mod tidy --> removes dependencies from go.mod 
go mod vendor --> removes libraries from vendor
```

This will remove all unused libraries